# Stuck on IF statement for signature file generation

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, xml-signature

I'm trying to create a signature script and I haven't been able to quite wrap my head around this just yet.
I'd like to print " |M " where the `If` statement is if there is a mobile value entered in the AD for that user other wise just carry on through the rest of the script.
(I know my `If` statement doesn't work but I thought I'd leave it there to a bit of clarity about what I want.)

```vb
'Contact line
objSelection.Font.Size = 8
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
objSelection.TypeText "P: " & strPhone
objSelection.TypeText " | D: " & strDirect

If strmobile = hasvalue Then
    objSelection.typetext " | M: " & strMobile
    If strmobile = empty Then
    EndIf

    objSelection.TypeText " | E: " & strEmail
    objSelection.TypeText " | W: " & strWebsite
    objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9).

> ```
> ' Block syntax: 
> If condition Then
>    [statements]
> [ElseIf condition-n Then
>    [elseifstatements]] . . .
> [Else
>    [elsestatements]]
> End If
> ```

When using block syntax each `If` statement *must* be closed by a corresponding `End If`. Also, it's `End If`, not `EndIf`.

If you want to insert something when `strmobile` has a value and do nothing otherwise you'd express that like this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(strmobile) Then
    objSelection.typetext " | M: " & strMobile
EndIf
```

Note that `Empty`, `Null`, and the empty string (`""`) are different values in VBScript, so depending on the actual value of `strmobile` you may need to adjust the check accordingly.

Comment: Thanks mate but won't that print " | M: " with no number after it? I'm trying to make it so it prints " |M: " only if it has the value.

Comment: @NickSchmidt My bad. That was supposed to be `If Not IsEmpty()`. Fixed.